# Feature space selection for river sand classification using multispectral imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, classification

I want to perform supervised classification for river sand detection. I have 3 m spatial resolution Surface Reflectance multispectral imagery with B, G, R and NIR bands (Planet data). Which all features should I choose for classification input that would give best separation for my sample dataset?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your feature space is tiny - only four variables. Any reasonable classification method is designed to deal with a significantly larger feature space, so there is no need to reduce the data set.

As such, go ahead and use all the available data.
Many methodologies will also provide a 'ranking' of features, which will indicate how useful a given feature was for the classification. This information can then be used to guide you towards which spectral bands are the most important for your study.

Comment: Can you please name any of the methodologies that provide ranking of features?

Comment: Random Forest is one of the standard ones that I use for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend including all of the spectral bands (R,G,B, NIR) *and* a vegetation index such as [normalized difference vegetation index (NDVI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_difference_vegetation_index), which utilizes the red and near infrared bands. The NDVI index will especially help your classification algorithm separate vegetation and water classes from the river sand.